# Login even if the user not registered with us in data base

Tags: php, session, authentication

Please help me for the following code of my login1.php file as a result of which when some user who is even not registered in our data base, if fill any information or no information as username and password shows has logged in. while it should only be logged in after matching its data from database and should go to commonfile.php.

my code is as under :

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include "backoffice/include/config.php";
$user=$_REQUEST['user'];

 $pass=$_REQUEST['pass'];
 $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
 $pid=$_REQUEST['pid'];
 $curr=$_REQUEST['curr'];
 $reqtype = $_REQUEST["window"];

//  echo $curr;  
//$link_name=$_REQUEST['id'];

$query=mysql_query("select * from member where email='".addslashes($user)."' and password        ='".addslashes($pass)."' and status='Yes'");
$counts = mysql_num_rows($query);
$rows  = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$_SESSION['uid']= $rows['id'];
$_SESSION['userid']=$rows['email'];
$_SESSION['user']=$rows['email'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){header("location:index.php");exit;}
if(!isset($_SESSION['session_id']))
{

                    if(isset($reqtype) && $reqtype=="offline")
                    {
                     header("location:offline.php?id=$user");       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    header("location:commonfile.php");
                    } 

}else{

                    if($count!="" )
                    {
                        header("location:signin.php?mess=error");
                    }else{
                        //header("location:place_order.php?id=$id&pid=$pid#mess");//
                        header("location:commonfile.php");

                    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to actually state a question. Please do that. Ask it as specifically as possible. Clearly structure your question. Don't ask for "please solve my problem", but describe which aspects of the problem you've already tackled.

Comment: You shouldn't store passwords in plain text in your database, but only a hash. You shouldn't use `addslashes` but `mysql_real_escape_string`. In fact you shouldn't even use the mysql_ functions, but rather use Mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

You have **$_SESSION['uid']= $rows['id'];** so even if **$rows** is empty (which should give you at least a warning) checking for **if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))** will always be false, because **$_SESSION['uid'];** is set.

Instead you should check if **$counts > 0**.
Also you should only set the **$_SESSION** variables when **$counts > 0**.

> Last but not least using the mysql_ functions is considered deprecated.
>   Please look into PDO it is a lot more secure.